# Do you have any idea how Google Docs Javascript do the interval data autorefresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, design-patterns

Alright, Here it goes:

I'm currently implementing a software which autorefresh/autopull/autoreload the data to keep the screen live by using AJAX.

This is actually working, but I know I´ve used the simplest approach which is:

1. SetInterval (javascript)
2. Call the Refresh Method over and over each n seconds.
3. Read the Json Data, rebuild the HTML and update it.

This can also be done by just calling a SetTimeOut (javascript) and the end of the AJAX request.

In the refresh method I internally check that it´s not being called simultaneously, etc.

However... this is the simplest approach, it works but, in slow computers, firefox and ie, I can see this activity sometimes freezes the browser, and I know this might not be necessary because of the *AJAX call*, but how "intensive" is the javascript operation overall... but, after running a profiler, Overall javascript (using jquery by the way) seem to be fine. Also if I disable the autorefresh, the browser wont freeze by short seconds in slow computers.

I decided to investigate how several of the majors AJAX applications works out there.

Facebook for instance.. they **do** a request all the time, every N seconds, interpret the JSON and update the screen, but, google docs... I can seem to find any request.. This is maybe because: they are just telling the javascript debugger engine that they do not want their request to be logged??, or, are they using another approach to the refresh dilemma?

I read in another answer here at stackoverflow, that Google Docs keeps an open connection..

Can this be the answer? http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming

What do you guys know about this?

Just as a side note, the application I´m developing is meant to be accessed by thousands of users at a time, and I know the JavaScript refresh routine only tells a little part of the history, but the Server Side Application and the database is currently supporting such a load according to the stress tests I did by using several thousands of virtualized stations. I just want to know what you think about the **client** browser problem specifically.

Regards and 
If you are still reading this.. 
Thanks you for your time.

Comment: You can't tell a debugger not to log anything...

Comment: But what if de bugger won't log anything? (sorry, bad joke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect they're using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Browser support is flaky, so your mileage may vary with this approach.

You may also want to look at [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) (ajax push engine), which is a decent implementation of long polling with a client/server architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on [Long Polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). But then you'll have to handle dropped connections etc.